# How to set special price for specific customer group

Tags: magento2, price, discount, customer-group

Guys I'm wondering how to add special price for specific customer group? For example, I have a group called **"VIP"**, I want to set *10% discount* on every product for this specified group only. Thank you in advance.

Comment: lets suppose you have a group then you must have a unique identity to diff them from rest of groups put a check on that unique identity on checkout if that person is shopping is from VIP show them or give them discount on amount else return them as it is working before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Catalog Price Rules:

[image: 30% discount rule]

Don't forget to run reindex and clean cache.

Another way is to use a cart price rules without coupon for specific customers, but in that case discount will be visible only on the cart page and checkout, but not visible in catalog.